# Do linear theories have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, maxwell-equations, superposition, linear-algebra, linear-systems

It is said that, in a linear theory, you can add any number of solutions to still find a solution. So, say I initially found three solutions to a linear theory, and I call them a1, a2, and a3. Now I can add a1 and a2 and call the sum a4 (a1+a2=a4), so a4 also becomes a solution. Then I can add a4 to a1 so a4+a1=a5 becomes a solution. This way, it becomes like a chain reaction and can reach upto infinity. Does it mean all linear theories have infinite number of solutions?
Examples of linear theories can be Maxwell’s theory of electromagnetism, Quantum Mechanics, etc.

Comment: Consider the linear theory $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)=0$. It has general solution $f(x)=a$, for any $a\in\mathbb R$. Is this a single solution? or an infinite number of solutions (one for each $a$)?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform For a given expression of f(x), I would say it is a single solution. If we define an expression ( f(x) ) in reality, then we’ll always have an assigned value for the “a”, am I right? Then won’t it be better to view it as a single solution? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions of a linear theory are a vector space. Vectors are things that can be added together and multiplied by numbers.

If $a_1$ is a solution, so is $2a_1$, $3a_1$, etc. If $a_1$ and $a_2$ are solutions, so are $Aa_1 + Ba_2$ for any numbers $A$ and $B$.

There are always an infinite number of vectors in a vector space. (OK, except for the trivial $0D$ vector space.)

But if you have two different solutions that are not multiples of each other, it does not generate a chain reaction of solutions. It generates a $2D$ vector space of solutions.

Comment: Can I infer from your answer that the number of original solutions (that are not multiples among themselves) correspond to the number of dimensions of the vector space?

Comment: Yes. The maximum number of linearly independent solutions is the dimension. Any maximal set of linearly independent solutions is a basis for the vector space. Though it gets a bit more complicated when the number is infinite.

Comment: Not all vector spaces have infinite cardinality. A finite dimensional vector space over a finite field will have finitely many elements. It's just that physics usually deals with vector spaces over infinite fields.

Comment: @Sandejo - True. The numbers that multiply vectors must be a field. The fields that physics usually uses are the real numbers and the complex numbers.